# Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function - Google Sign in Error - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-signin

I am trying to use Google Sign In to my react app and I am able to perform google login successfully on development but I am not able to do google login in Production.

This is the npm module I am using to authenticate through google.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login

I am getting the following error in my production build.

```
Uncaught TypeError: r is not a function
    at google-login.js:1
    at e.zo (cb=gapi.loaded_0:200)
    at lk (cb=gapi.loaded_0:203)
    at gk (cb=gapi.loaded_0:203)
    at _.Rj.hU (cb=gapi.loaded_0:203)
    at Qj (cb=gapi.loaded_0:195)
```

What I have tried is that, after a very long time again it works and if I clear cache it works. So kindly tell me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add analytics api in Google developer console , that solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when my onSuccess callback mistakenly tried to access a field on the result that did not exist. I honestly have no idea why, or if this will be helpful, but that's what helped my code.